# Is JavaServer Faces 1.2 deprecated?

Tags: jsf

I have a question about JavaServer Faces. The ([Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces)) about the technology claims that all versions prior to (and including) JSF 1.2 are deprecated. Is there any official data to support this claim? I googled for a while but with no success.

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: Thoughworks (with Chief Architect Martin Fowler) suggests that the whole Java should be deprecated soon... ;-)

Comment: @Tuomas Hietanen, only for client-side. Applets really should be deprecated, but not server-side code, obviously. And I note its been 4 years since your comment and Java is still alive and well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia page is massively out of date. The [download page](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html) says that version 1.2_15 was released on 24 September 2010. There's nothing I can find at the JSF pages about 1.2 being deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia.. *sigh*. I fixed the page. JSF 1.2 is currently definitely not deprecated. It must have been a poor word choice of the wiki page maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say so. It's obsolete, but not deprecated.